# Is my Kentia Palm beyond saving?

Tags: plant-health

I bought two Kentia palms about a month ago and over the last few days they seem to be dying. I noticed that a lot of the lower leaves were going very dark and turning crunchy so I cut those off at the stem to give the rest of the plant a chance. Both palms seem to be losing leaves by the day though. The bigger fronds at the top haven't been affected but they're not looking as full of life as they used to.

I water them only when I can feel the top two inches of soil have dried out. I recently repotted them out of the containers they came in and I didn't notice any problems with the roots (although I'm new to this so I would have easily missed any issues).

Thanks

Comment: We really need a photo or two please... and when you repotted, did you use pots with drainage holes  in the base, along with new potting soil, or some other soil?